# Show userform and hide only the active workbook

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm having other problem, i want my userform to show up but i want ONLY the active workbook hidden on the same time.

The problem is that all the other excel files that i have open, also became hidden, and when i try to open some other workbook, it doesn't open and automatically becomes hidden also.

thanks

I tried to show the userform from the workbook, and at the same time, that workbook becomes hidden, but the other excel files i have open also becomes hidden.

```
Sub Abrir_Templates_BackOffice()

Application.Visible = True
TemplatesBackOffice.Show


End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to post the code you're having problems with.

Comment: Sub Abrir_Templates_BackOffice()


Application.Visible = True
TemplatesBackOffice.Show

    
    

End Sub

Comment: `activeworkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False` should hide the activeworkbook

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: What does it do *instead of* work?  A little more info is always useful.

Comment: I'm sorry. It hides only the workbook im working on (ok in here), but also hides the userform that i don't want.

Comment: Is your userform modal or modeless?

Comment: It's vbmodeless

Comment: I tested hiding a workbook with a modeless userform showing, and the userform was still visible.  Not sure what's different between my setup and yours.

Comment: Does it goes like this?

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
''Application.Visible = False
TemplatesBackOffice.Show

End Sub

Comment: The workbook (in the userform) hides but all the other excel files i have open also hides, and i don't want that.

Comment: `Application.Visible = False` would hide everything I think.

Comment: When i open the workbook, the userform opens automatically and hides the workbook at the same time, then i have a option on the userform to go back to the workbook and close the userform, and in the workbook i have a macro to hide the workbook and show the userform again. 
The problem is when the userform shows to hide the workbook, all the excel files i have open also hide.
Do i have to specify the workbook to close and then userfom.show?